# How do I fix a Python Function to iterate through a list of JSON files in a directory and merge into a Single JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a device which constantly generates JSON files - a.json, b.json, c.json and so on and stores them in a folder directory as shown below.

```
“Data/d/a.json” 
“Data/d/b.json”
“Data/d/c.json”
.
.
.
.
“Data/d/g.json”
```

Sample data in each JSON file

a.json

```
{"artist":null,"auth":"Logged In","firstName":"Walter","gender":"M","itemInSession":0,"lastName":"Frye","length":null,"level":"free","location":"San Francisco-Oakland-Hayward, CA","method":"GET","page":"Home","registration":1540919166796.0,"sessionId":38,"song":null,"status":200,"ts":1541105830796,"userAgent":"\"Mozilla\/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/36.0.1985.143 Safari\/537.36\"","userId":"39"}
{"artist":null,"auth":"Logged In","firstName":"Kaylee","gender":"F","itemInSession":0,"lastName":"Summers","length":null,"level":"free","location":"Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ","method":"GET","page":"Home","registration":1540344794796.0,"sessionId":139,"song":null,"status":200,"ts":1541106106796,"userAgent":"\"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/35.0.1916.153 Safari\/537.36\"","userId":"8"}
```

b.json

```
{"artist":"Des'ree","auth":"Logged In","firstName":"Kaylee","gender":"F","itemInSession":1,"lastName":"Summers","length":246.30812,"level":"free","location":"Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ","method":"PUT","page":"NextSong","registration":1540344794796.0,"sessionId":139,"song":"You Gotta Be","status":200,"ts":1541106106796,"userAgent":"\"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/35.0.1916.153 Safari\/537.36\"","userId":"8"}
{"artist":null,"auth":"Logged In","firstName":"Kaylee","gender":"F","itemInSession":2,"lastName":"Summers","length":null,"level":"free","location":"Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ","method":"GET","page":"Upgrade","registration":1540344794796.0,"sessionId":139,"song":null,"status":200,"ts":1541106132796,"userAgent":"\"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/35.0.1916.153 Safari\/537.36\"","userId":"8"}
```

c.json

```
{"artist":"Mr Oizo","auth":"Logged In","firstName":"Kaylee","gender":"F","itemInSession":3,"lastName":"Summers","length":144.03873,"level":"free","location":"Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ","method":"PUT","page":"NextSong","registration":1540344794796.0,"sessionId":139,"song":"Flat 55","status":200,"ts":1541106352796,"userAgent":"\"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/35.0.1916.153 Safari\/537.36\"","userId":"8"}
{"artist":"Tamba Trio","auth":"Logged In","firstName":"Kaylee","gender":"F","itemInSession":4,"lastName":"Summers","length":177.18812,"level":"free","location":"Phoenix-Mesa-Scottsdale, AZ","method":"PUT","page":"NextSong","registration":1540344794796.0,"sessionId":139,"song":"Quem Quiser Encontrar O Amor","status":200,"ts":1541106496796,"userAgent":"\"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/35.0.1916.153 Safari\/537.36\"","userId":"8"}
```

These files can grow to as many as 1000 JSON files a day and thousand files in a week. To further process the data in these JSON files, I have to bulk insert the data in each JSON file into PostgreSQL as you can see in my code snippet below, but the current process is just too manual and inefficient because I insert each file one after the other.

```
import json
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=devicedb user=#### password=####")
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.set_session(autocommit=True)
cursor.execute("create table if not exists events_table(artist text, auth text, firstName text, gender varchar, itemInSession int, lastName text, length text, level text, location text, method varchar, page text, registration text, sessionId int, song text, status int, ts bigint, userAgent text, userId int );")

data = []
with open('Data/d/a.json ') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

columns = [
    'artist',
    'auth',
    'firstName',
    'gender',
    'itemInSession',
    'lastName',
    'length',
    'level',
    'location',
    'method',
    'page',
    'registration',
    'sessionId',
    'song',
    'status',
    'ts',
    'userAgent',
    'userId'
]

for item in data:
    my_data = [item[column] for column in columns]
    for i, v in enumerate(my_data):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            my_data[i] = json.dumps(v)

    insert_query = "INSERT INTO events_table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(my_data))
```

To improve on the current process, I searched online and found this function below for merging multiple files into a single file. My understanding of this function is that I can just define my output_filename and input_filenames by pointing to the merged.json as my merged file and the directory containing my list of input JSON files and then run the function, but it seems I am wrong. Please, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
def cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames):
    with file(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
        first = True
        for infile_name in input_filenames:
            with file(infile_name) as infile:
                if first:
                    outfile.write('[')
                    first = False
                else:
                    outfile.write(',')
                outfile.write(mangle(infile.read()))
        outfile.write(']')

output_filename = 'data/d/merged.json'
input_filenames = 'data/d/*.json'
cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames)
```

I got the following errors

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3ff012d91d76> in <module>()
      1 output_filename = 'data/d/merged.json'
      2 input_filenames = 'data/d/*.json'
----> 3 cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames)

<ipython-input-18-760b670f79b1> in cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames)
      1 def cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames):
----> 2     with file(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
      3         first = True
      4         for infile_name in input_filenames:
      5             with file(infile_name) as infile:

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

@deusxmachine thank you for your contribution, I changed the function as advised to:

```
def cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames):
    with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
        first = True
        for infile_name in input_filenames:
            with open(infile_name) as infile:
                if first:
                    outfile.write('[')
                    first = False
                else:
                    outfile.write(',')
                outfile.write(mangle(infile.read()))
        outfile.write(']')
```

The code created merged.Json file but with no content and with the following error

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-40d7387f704a> in <module>()
      1 output_filename = 'merged.json'
      2 input_filenames = 'data/d/*.json'
----> 3 cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames)

<ipython-input-15-951cbaba7765> in cat_json(output_filename, input_filenames)
      3         first = True
      4         for infile_name in input_filenames:
----> 5             with open(infile_name) as infile:
      6                 if first:
      7                     outfile.write('[')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd'
```

I cannot figure out why it gives the errors above and says no such file or directory. a.json, b.json, c.json ... resides in the directory 'data/d/' or do I need to mention each file names instead of *.json?

Answer (score 1):

I really dont understand by what you meant by merging JSONs, but I know why are you getting that error

Instead of

```
with file(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
```

Do this

```
with open(output_filename, "w") as outfile:
```

`file` is not a function.`open` is used to open files

Hope it helps

Comment: By merging the JSON files I mean to combine the content of a.json, b.json, c.json ... and so on into a single JSON file - merged.json